# Local Load Balancer Connections Limit above 2500 hasn't pricing api's in SoftLayer?

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Once we upgrade connections of VIP type Local Load Balancer above 2500 it upgrades to 5000, 7500, 10000 etc. On SoftLayer It shows the price but I am unable to find pricing apis for the same. Anyone has any idea how can I get pricing for the upgraded connections after 2500?

Answer (score 0):

The [upgradeItem](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/#upgradeItem) object into the billing item returns the next product item in the upgrade path.

Try with the following rest request, it returns prices of upgradeItem by location. If your location isn't in the response then use the price with `locationGroupId = null`, it is a standard price.

`https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress/[idLoadBalancer]/getObject?objectMask=mask[id,billingItem[ id,upgradeItem[prices[pricingLocationGroup[locations]]],description]]`

You can also use `upgradeItems` instead of `upgradeItem`, it will return all next connection limits and their prices. But take into account you will be only able to upgrade the LB in the next connection limit and not directly to a higher one.

If you want to retrieve same data for all local LBs in your account then use [getAdcLoadBalancers](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getAdcLoadBalancers/) with the same mask

Comment: Thanks Albert. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Albert ...Want one more help related to the same.I am trying to verify order for LLB with connections equal to 5000 getting following error:
"The price Load Balancer 5,000 VIP Connections (80473) is not valid for package (194)."
Any idea?

Comment: I couldn't retrieve the price 80473 using getItemPrices, in fact I couldn't see a price for 5,000 VIP connections on package 194.

Comment: The prices listed into the upgradeItem or upgradeItems cannot be ordered directly those prices are specifically to upgrade only

Comment: Yeah Exactly Albert, we cant see the 5,000 VIP connections on package 194. I am upgrading the connections from 2,500 to 5,000 so while upgrading I want to hit verify order call to check the price Id I am sending is right or wrong for the  selected datacenter?

Comment: I think you wont be able to do that, i reviewed and the upgradeItem doesn't requires parameters, it upgrades to the next connection limit in the same datacenter. I tested and it seems the next price is an standard price so I think this is good since that prices are cheaper

Comment: When I said " upgradeItem doesn't requires parameters" I mean the method https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress/upgradeConnectionLimit/ doesn't requires parameters like price id or location

Comment: Okay. Thanks Albert.